# Javamail : Proper way to issue idle() for IMAPFolder

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have set MessageCountListener for IMAPFolder. In order to get updates continuously I had to do the following, which is a killer for my app performance wise. It freezes the GUI since it's running for each and every folder.

```
while (true) {
     try {
          if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) {
              folder.idle();
          } else {
              getSyncListenersAttachedFolders().remove(syncFolder.getFolderID());
          }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
          errorLOG.error("IDLE command issue exception.");
          getSyncListenersAttachedFolders().remove(syncFolder.getFolderID());
     }
}
```

Is there any better way of issuing idle command which will not run in a while(true) condition.
Expecting a quick response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it in its own thread.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: But that is the answer.  The way you're expected to use the idle command is to run it in a loop, and because of that you should not run it in the GUI thread but rather in a thread of its own.

Comment: You could have been a little more descriptive in yiu answer, explaining what was wrong and how to fix it.